# 20kHz sine wave signal amplification

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal

I'm trying to amplify a sine wave voltage signal by two at high frequencies (20kHz) I've tried using an op-amp as the frequency gets this high the wave turns triangular (I'm assuming this is to do with the slew rate).

Is there another way to amplify this signal across the frequencies of 1-20kHz and keep the sine wave?

Comment: Post schematics and the scope output if possible. 20kHz shouldn't be a problem. You did not mention the voltage of your output.

Comment: Opamp: http://puu.sh/y8eEZ/440eee05d5.png

Input and output waves: http://puu.sh/y8eGI/20e8bee27e.png

Comment: Have you ever heard of "audio amplifiers"?

Comment: If you use an op-amp with a higher specified slew rate, then it will work better. Hint, almost *any* op-amp is faster than a 741.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.kepcopower.com/nomoslew.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 741 op-amp has a very low slew rate, 0.5V/uS if I recall correctly.

Something like a TLO71/2/4 at 13V/uS would be far better if you want to stick with old and low cost common op-amps, or an OP275 at 22V/uS is aimed at the pro-audio market.

In fact, almost *any* op-amp that isn't billed as 'micropower' will out slew a 741.